# How to initialize a jquery function onSuccess of ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to initialize a jquery function when the ajax request is done and got response successfuly. Because am trying to get a table as ajax response and sort it out as a grid using data table jquery plugin for girds

The function initializes this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#data_grid').dataTable();
    } );
```

Function which will be triggered on success of the ajax response

```
function showgValid()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete")
    {document.getElementById('loadingImg').style.display='none';
    data =xmlHttp.responseText;

    document.getElementById("genPay").innerHTML=data;

    }
}
```

On success of the ajax response, the innerHTML of genPay div will become the responsetext,
 the response text will be a table with an id data_table.

The ajax request will be sent and got from the file below:

```
 <?

require_once '../config.php';

$db = $_GET['db'];

$table = $_GET['table'];

$_SESSION['table']=$table; 

 ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "demo_page.css";
            @import "demo_table.css";
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script language ="javascript" src="js/abtAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#data_grid').dataTable();
            } );



        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="dt_example">
        <div id="container">






<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"  id="data_grid">

    <thead><?
    if ( $line == 0 )
    {

?>
<tr>
    <?php
     $sql=mysql_query("show columns from $table");
     while($res = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
     {
     echo "<th bgcolor='".( ( $line % 2 ) ==0 ? '#efefef' : '#ffffff'  )."'>$res[0]</td>";

     }
    ?>
</tr>
<?
}
$line++;
?>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
$result = mysql_query( "select * from $table" ); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_object($result)){ 
print "<tr>";
foreach ($get_info as $field) 
print "<td>$field</td>"; 
print "</tr>"; 
} 

?>
    </tbody>
<?
print "</table>"; 
?>


            <div class="spacer"></div>






        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that am not getting the grid am expecting. I think the function is not initializing on success of the ajax request. please correct me to get rid of this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` will not fire after your ajax call.  It only fires when the page is first loaded.  If you want `$('#data_grid').dataTable();` called after your ajax call, then just call it from the success handler of the ajax call.

```
function showgValid()
{
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete")
    {
        document.getElementById('loadingImg').style.display='none';
        data =xmlHttp.responseText;

        document.getElementById("genPay").innerHTML=data;

        // ADD THIS LINE to your ajax success handler
        $('#data_grid').dataTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

[jQuery API refference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)